# DateTime.ParseExact, Ignore the timezone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, xml-parsing

If I have a date such as `2011-05-05T11:35:47.743-04:00`

How can I ignore the timezone (-04:00) when I do a DateTime.ParseExact programatically?

Comment: Do you not care about the timezone or would you like the result adjusted for the offset?

Comment: What is your expected output given your example string?

Comment: Why do you want to ignore it? Store it in UTC

Comment: What I would like to keep is 2011-05-05 11:35:47

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
DateTimeOffset dt =DateTimeOffset.Parse("2011-05-05T11:35:47.743-04:00", null);
```

Comment: You can get the `DateTime` via `dt.DateTime`, or is it you are not on 3.5 ?

Comment: your name was appropriate for the facial expression I imagine you would have been pulling then.