# Parsing ISO 8601 with timezone to .NET datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, iso8601

I have an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601) timestamp in the format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn][{+|-}hh:mm]

YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[{+|-}hh:mm]
```

Examples:

```
2013-07-03T02:16:03.000+01:00

2013-07-03T02:16:03+01:00
```

How can I parse it to a .NET Framework `DateTime` with correct `TimeZone` supplied?

The `DateTime.TryParse` doesn't work because the trailing info regarding the `TimeZone`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTime.ParseExact, Ignore the timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676856/datetime-parseexact-ignore-the-timezone)

Answer (score 18):

You should be able to format it using `DateTimeOffset` and the [`K` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#KSpecifier). You can then convert that to a `DateTime` afterwards if you want to. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "2013-07-03T02:16:03.000+01:00";
        string pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFK";
        DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact
            (text, pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dto);
    }
}
```

One thing to note is that this is badly named - it's not actually a time zone, it's just a UTC offset. It *doesn't* actually tell you the original time zone. (There can be several different time zones observing the same offset at the same time.)

Or with [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) (unstable version, which will become 1.2 pretty soon):

```
string text = "2013-07-03T02:16:03.000+01:00";
OffsetDateTimePattern pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.ExtendedIsoPattern;
OffsetDateTime odt = pattern.Parse(text).Value; 
Console.WriteLine(odt);
```